# C# How can I deploy my project solution and connecting to remote SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am working on a Windows Forms application written in C#, and using Entity Framework 6 to connect to a SQL Server database, currently on the same local computer -- which I will be separating on another computer on production of course.

Now, would I need to alter anything before building the release? Or would the program find the database automatically when connected on the same local network?

Comment: You would need to change the connection string, yes.

Comment: If you put the correct server name into the connection string, and that server can be contacted, and you can  communicate on the required port, and you are not using windows authentication then it will function. The biggest gotcha for most people is the port - make sure that the SQL Server port is open in the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to remote SQL by changing connection string from `App.Config`.

You can use `server name : IP\SqlExpress, 5012`.

Here IP is your public IP where DB is setup and 5012 is random port.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. Is it possible to change the connection string from using C#? or would I need to do that manually?

Comment: In production  solution you have to change App.Config. You have to do it manually.